# Pkhex not loading 'main' in Wine?

Tags: technical-issues, linux, pokemon-sixth-generation, cheats

Pkhex doesn't load my Alpha Sapphire save for some reason. Pkhex doesn't support Linux natively and thus needs to be run through Wine, could this be caused by Wine?

I'm using oothax to get ftbrony and save dumper working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as PKHex is a Gen6 save editor which I don't believe is legal content for this website.

Comment: @oamlyya, save editing is not illegal in any shape or form.

Comment: @Timelord64 - while true, it **is** a cheating tool which we're a bit gray on. The question is whether we consider PKHex a single-player cheat tool (which we're ok with) or a multiplayer cheat tool (which we're not ok with). It could be claimed that it's being used to gain an advantage over your opponents by genning perfect Pokemon (not having to worry with breeding/training and only focusing on battling), or by adding or unlocking hard-to-get items/Pokemon you can enter into trades that favour you (i.e. Not blinking at trading away your shiny Pokemon or legendary because you've cloned it).

Comment: Or it could be claimed that it's 'only a Save Editor' in the strictest sense and that it only really affects the single-player experience. (It doesn't, but I can see that argument being made).

Comment: @Robotnik, I agree with the morality reason. However, I think it should be raised in meta (simply for point of reference, if not already done), and listed as a separate reason. Morality is a grey topic, but legality is clearly not, at least in this case. There is a very big difference between cheating in a game and breaking the law.

Comment: @Robotnik 99% sure battle spot and such has anti-hack in place. Besides, ever heard of balanced hackmons?

Comment: @AlexanderM - I never said anything about Battle Spot, nor about 'hackmons'. The advantages gained from cheating aren't in battle, they're in short-circuiting the breeding/training process. Someone who spends 3 months breeding a team vs someone who gens 20 different teams and spend 3 months battling, who do you think has the advantage?

Comment: @Robotnik the cheaters advantage, in your scenario, is experience. That's it. But some people simply hate the mandatory training period because it's unnecessary when you could just gem to skip it

Comment: @AlexanderM - Hate it or not, the breeding/training mechanics *are* a part of the game and short circuiting it puts some players at an advantage - by affording them more time to get the experience as you've said. It's not a viable argument to say that *"everyone should therefore cheat"*, nor is it enough to say *"if you don't cheat you should put more hours into the game to make up for it"* because not everyone can afford to do those things, therefore while cheating devices like PKHex exists there will always be an inbalance of power.

Comment: Note that I wasn't actually looking to get drawn into an argument about it, I can also see the benefits (and have no doubt indirectly benefited from it) - trying to pry Version-specific legends off people is hard if they don't clone them! I only care whether Arqade had deemed that we support it or not - if we do, this is the last you'll hear of it.